# Div tags stacking one another

Tags: html, css, tags, stack

I need some help with some CSS issues.

I am trying to create a series of buttons using div tags.  The problem is that they are all stacking together as one.

The code is at http://codepen.io/CliffTam/pen/gadEaq

Can someone take a look at the code and advice me on how to fix this?

I try creating a separate DIV tag class 'box' and set display:block.

```
div.box {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Yet, they are still staying together.

Thanks!
Cliff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;`, for both the `.box` and `.profile-image` that stacks them.

By absolutely positioning them, they were sticking to the top left, meaning all were essentially merging into one...

http://codepen.io/samuidavid/pen/JYaVOQ